# Gitlab history strange behavior

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm facing a problem with GitLab and local file history:

On our instance, the file `FTLParam.cpp` has the following last change

[image]

But, when clicking on the History button, this shows up

[image]

There are 3 more changes, made recently, that seems to be ignored. In fact, the file has the changes from commit `2ed742cb`.

Locally, the last change is shown correctly:

```
> git log FTLParam.cpp
commit 2ed742cb90ed951f046811f0314c432aec330033
Author: Gabriele Zampieri <...>
Date:   Tue Mar 31 15:36:13 2020 +0200

    libs: eeprom: ported a fix
```

The extra commits were part of a previous merge request, merged the April 14th. Doing a compare between the source branch and `develop` does not list such commits. We actually needs the file to be aligned with `c252f039`.

Can someone help me investigate this issue?

Best regards, 
Gabriele

Comment: Git itself does not have file history. The only history in a repository is the set of commits in the repository. Hence GitLib must be showing you some selected subset of commits, similar to what Git does when you ask `git log` to show you only *some* commits, rather than all history. Note that `git log FTLParam.cpp` specifically *excludes* a lot of stuff: if you want Git itself to include everything, you need `git log --full-history FTLParam.cpp`. What GitLab does, I do not know.

Comment: Thankyou @torek the `--full-history` flag shows the 3 extra commit!

Answer (score 0):

As torek commented: run `git log --full-history FTLParam.cpp`.

Compare that to what you get from `git log FTLParam.cpp`.

See if that accounts for the difference.

The `git-log` man page says:

```
   The following options affect the way the simplification is performed:


   Default mode
       Simplifies the history to the simplest history explaining the final state of the tree. Simplest because it
       prunes some side branches if the end result is the same (i.e. merging branches with the same content)

   --full-history
       Same as the default mode, but does not prune some history.
```